# How to adopt MVC to server with GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I write simple server with GUI in java SE. So I want to use MVC. But I have trouble with handle of many client connection problem in Controller.
I have thises classes:

- MainWindow - View
- ClientPanel - View - Part of MainWindow. Each ClientPanel object should represent each connection with specific client and show parameters of this client
- Controller
- Server - thread which wait for a client a run new thread for handle connection
- ClientConnectionHandler - thread which handle connection with client

So how to a "connect" ClientPanel with ClientConnectionHandler using Conrtoller?

I think that I should add some interface to MainWindow (or maybe to ClienPanel) and some how pass it to Controller. And maybe do same wich ClientConnectionHandler.
But what interface, where?

Comment: MVC is an Architectural pattern. Are you using some specific MVC Framework?  If you use J2EE the container takes care of handling multiple connections.

Comment: I use Java SE. Without any specific Framework.

Comment: I suggest you look at couple of servlet tutorials. You should be using j2ee .You can take a look at this - http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html

Comment: :( I have to use java SE 1.6